# timer with loop repeat the first result all the time java?

Tags: java, loops, timer

I tried many times with this code many times to make it print the letters with 4 second wait between letters ***But*** it just print the first letter then repeat it all the time !

```
 StatusBar.getInstance().ShowMoves.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         StatusBar.getInstance().ShowMoves.setEnabled(false);
         sol=null;
         sol = StatusBar.getInstance().getSolution();
         Timer timer = new Timer(); 
         for (int tbn = 0; tbn < sol.length(); tbn++) { 
             temp = tbn ;

             timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                 @Override                                
                 public void run() {                        
                     switch (sol.charAt(temp)) {   
                         case 'u': 
                             StatusBar.getInstance().TimeTaken.setText(StatusBar.getInstance().TimeTaken.getText()+"u");
                             break;
                         case'd':
                             StatusBar.getInstance().TimeTaken.setText(StatusBar.getInstance().TimeTaken.getText()+"d");
                             break;
                         case'l':
                             StatusBar.getInstance().TimeTaken.setText(StatusBar.getInstance().TimeTaken.getText()+"l");
                             break;
                         case'r':
                             StatusBar.getInstance().TimeTaken.setText(StatusBar.getInstance().TimeTaken.getText()+"r");
                             break;
                         }        
                         try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                             Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                         }
                     }}, 4000);
                 }
             }
         }
     );                                                                                               
     this.pack();

     KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
            .addKeyEventDispatcher(Controller.getInstance());
 }
```

What is the wrong with the code ?

Comment: You will find this piece of documentation helpful:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score 0):

Taken from documentation, reference can be found below:

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws InterruptedException {
        String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };

        for (int i = 0;
             i < importantInfo.length;
             i++) {
            //Pause for 4 seconds
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            //Print a message
            System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29

Comment: i used thread.sleep without the timer just like this code but it shows all the letters at the same time with the JLabel BUT it works well with System.out.println ; ! =(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the loop inside the timer instead of timer inside the loop

```
StatusBar.getInstance().ShowMoves.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    StatusBar.getInstance().ShowMoves.setEnabled(false);
                    sol=null;
                    sol = StatusBar.getInstance().getSolution();
                    Timer timer = new Timer(); 

                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override                                
                    public void run() {

                        for (int tbn = 0; tbn < sol.length(); tbn++)
                    { 
                    switch (sol.charAt(tbn))
                    {

                        case 'u':
                            GamePanel.getInstance().moveUp();
                    {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                            break;
                        case'd':
                        GamePanel.getInstance().moveDown();
                        {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                            break;
                        case'l':
                         GamePanel.getInstance().moveLeft();
                        {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                            break;
                        case'r':
                        GamePanel.getInstance().moveRight();
                        {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                            break;

                    }} 


                             }}, 1000);

                    }






                }


            );




    this.pack();

    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
            .addKeyEventDispatcher(Controller.getInstance());
}
```